# Ambiguous column name error in SQlite in R

Tags: r, sqlite

I am new to SQL and wanted to make a query my database loaded into R (using SQLite)

I want to make some query similar to this one (but resolving the problem of the ambiguous column name):

```
        dbGetQuery(airline,'SELECT min (price) FROM routes 
        JOIN airports ON routes.departure = airports.airportID JOIN cities ON airports.city = cities.cityID AND cities.name = "Berlin"
        JOIN airports ON routes.arrival = airports.airportID AND cities.name = "London"')
```

In SQLite, it works out with the following statement:

```
         SELECT min(price) 
         FROM routes 
         WHERE routes.departure 
         IN

         (SELECT airportID
         FROM cities, airports
         WHERE
         airports.city = cities.cityID AND 
         cities.name = "Berlin" )
    
         AND routes.arrival IN 
         (SELECT airportID
         FROM cities, airports
         WHERE
         airports.city = cities.cityID AND 
         cities.name = "London" )
```

However, I did not find a way to translate it to R (I get the error: incomplete input).

Maybe someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an alias (a1, a2) for each instance of airline and use those aliases to avoid ambiguity.  We can also define aliases (r, c) for routes and cities to shorten the code.  Although not shown, it is suggested that price be qualified as well.

```
SELECT min (price) FROM routes as r
  JOIN airports as a1 ON r.departure = a1.airportID 
  JOIN cities as c ON a1.city = c.cityID AND c.name = "Berlin"
  JOIN airports as a2 ON r.departures = a2.airportID AND c.name = "London"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess, instead of "r.departures" it should be used "r.arrival". For whatever reason, the result is "NA". I get only a correct result for the departure If I leave out the last join.

Answer (score 0):

The following statement works:

```
dbGetQuery(airline, 'SELECT min(price) FROM routes
JOIN airports ON routes.departure = airports.airportID 
JOIN cities ON airports.city = cities.cityID AND cities.name = "Berlin"
JOIN airports as a1 ON routes.arrival = a1.airportID 
JOIN cities as c ON a1.city = c.cityID AND c.name = "London"')
```

By using the alias for the instance of cities the second reference to the name is adjusted to the join on routes.arrival.